# JS looping, through an HTML5 prompt button

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, animation

I am learning JS, and am trying to find the simplest, most elegant way to keep looping through an HTML input box and firing off an associated CSS animation based on what a user types in.

[Here](http://codepen.io/Widgeteria/pen/myLPWV) is the pen link, and the HTML only below:

```
<body>

<p>Click button to enter a string.</p>

<button  name="startButton" type="text" autofocus onclick="getString()">Click me!</button>

<div>
<p class="slug" id="demo"></p>
</div>

<script src="dullJack_src.js">
</script>

</body>
```

I get the feeling I have to code a JS callback function (which I am learning about), unless there is some much simpler way to keep looping through the HTML code.

It is almost as is I am trying to have a pseudo main section with a `while()` loop that executes the animation every time the user enters something.

Really stuck and would appreciate any feedback.  thanks!

Comment: What animation you want on prompt?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear to me. Loop through what? What could the user type to get an animation? Describe what the expected behavior would be like.

Comment: Is [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwRMpb) what you want to do?

Comment: Are you looking for the JS to listen to the input box and fire on each keystroke or just on hitting ok?

Comment: why not use html input elements instead of the popup, which needs that looping? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp To input element it is easier to attach callbacks as the element is all the time on screen. While loop on a web site seems little suspicious for me.

Comment: it seems that blex has found the answer right away!  i am not sure what he did (will have to study the code changes) but it seems to work perfectly.  many many thx to all of you for your help.  i was really stuck.  first time using stockoverflow so am not sure how to use this interface to direct this coment at blex, but again thank you!

Comment: outstanding.  i had no idea that JS was so weakly typed that you can assign an element / class to a string type